# In Datadog, is it possible to send multi alert base on each presence of log that match the query?

Tags: logging, alert, datadog

I want to send alert whenever a log that match query appears. I've tried to use a combination of Monitor and Query. But the problem is if there are many logs appear consecutively in a short span of time, the alert will only fire one.

Is it possible to make it fire one alert with each of the presence of the log?

Comment: Are all of these log lines conveying the same information (for example "order failed") or is each log line conveying something slightly different (for example "card declined", "Insufficient funds" etc) and you are trying to capture any of those things happening in a single monitor?

I don't think the exact solution that you described is possible but I am trying to understand why you want it to work that way to see are there alternative solutions.

Comment: all of these logs should be the same, the only difference will be the user id in the log string